# Daemon Sync Stuck: 0 Blocks Remaining

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, daemon, synchronization

Using Monero GUI Wallet in Simple Mode, which was apparently supposed to give me immediate Send/Receive functionality.

The Daemon Sync started off with "Daemon blocks remaining: 0" and has remained on that for hours, while still saying "Synchronizing". I restarted the Wallet & Daemon, but nothing changed.

Any advice on how to get the Daemon Synchronized?

Logs:
[2021/11/22 00:08] 2021-11-21 22:08:34.310 I Monero 'Oxygen Orion' (v0.17.2.3-release)
Height: 1, target: 1 (100%)
Downloading at 0 kB/s
Next needed pruning seed: 1
0 peers
0 spans, 0 MB
[]

OS:
Edition Windows 11 Home
Version 21H2
Installed on    ‎2021/‎11/‎20
OS build    22000.318
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22000.318.0

Additional Info:
3.5TB of Free Space on HD.
BitDefender Total Security "Potentially malicious application detected" and "Infected file detected", however I restored all the quarantined items, e.g. "The item D:\Monero\Monero GUI Wallet\monero-blockchain-prune.exe was restored at user request."

Comment: What do the status bars in the left bottom indicate?

Answer (score 0):

With Bitdefender Total Security you will need to set the Firewall rules as well as the antivirus exemption, as it will likely be blocking the connection.